# Mercurial heads

Tags: mercurial, branch

Here's what I did.  I don't want two heads.  How do I fix this?

```
~/src: hg push
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Neil/project
ruprojecting ssh hg@bitbucket.org 'hg -R Neil/project serve --stdio'
searching for changes
new remote heads on branch 'default'
new remote head e04226a528b5
abort: push creates new remote head e04226a528b5!
(did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)

~/src: hg push -f
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Neil/project
ruprojecting ssh hg@bitbucket.org 'hg -R Neil/project serve --stdio'
searching for changes
14 changesets found
remote: adding changesets
remote: adding manifests
remote: adding file changes
remote: added 14 changesets with 30 changes to 67 files (+1 heads)
remote: bb/acl: Neil is allowed. accepted payload.

~/src: hg pull
ruprojecting ssh hg@bitbucket.org 'hg -R Neil/project serve --stdio'
pulling from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/Neil/project
searching for changes
no changes found

~/src: hg heads
changeset:   1177:e04226a528b5
tag:         tip
parent:      1175:b5f77a454e64
user:        Neil
date:        Sat Feb 25 09:12:48 2012 -0800
files:       src/experiments/distribution_combination.py


changeset:   1176:f7cc8d94f4f3
parent:      1162:b680e6f93f80
user:        Neil
date:        Thu Feb 23 15:32:36 2012 -0800
files:       .hgignore src/CMakeLists.txt etc.
```

Comment: -1: Because it was just copied the output without any comments about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hg merge
```

That will prompt you to merge the two heads back into one. Rather, it will merge everything it can automatically, and prompt you about conflicts. Afterwards you can diff the result and submit it as a new changelist.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want additional heads - don't do it

**Instead** of dumb push -f:

- hg incoming && hg pull
- hg merge
- hg commit
- hg push

Answer (score 3):

This is usually an indication that someone else has pushed since you last pulled.  While you can provide the -f flag to force the push, as you have seen this just results in a new head.

The solution is to update to the head that you want to merge into, and run hg merge, then commit/push.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm the only one with write access.  I wonder how this happened?

Comment: Do you develop from multiple machines at times?  I have had the situation where I pushed some work from home, but when I went to work I went on fixing another bug forgetting about my own push earlier.

Comment: Hmmm… I'll keep that in mind, but I only have one development machine.

Comment: @NeilG - hg log will help you to see "How and where head added". Just to note - you, single developer on single workplace can get multiply heads: update to **previous changeset**, edit, commit, viola!!! get anonymous branch

Comment: @LazyBadger: That must have been it.  Thanks!